# Servlet Security question about j_security_check, j_username and j_password

Tags: java

I used jdbcRealm in my web application and it's working fine. I defined all constraints also in my web.xml. Like all pages of url pattern /Admin/* should be accessed by only admin. I have a login form with uses standard j_security_check, j_username and j_password.

Now, when i type Admin/home.jsf it rightly redirects me login.jsf and there when i type the password i am redirected to home.jsf. This works alright but problem comes i directly go to login.jsf and then type password and username. This time it again redirects me to login.jsf. Is there any way through which i can specify which page to go when successful login is there? I need to specify different different pages for different roles. For Admin, it is /Admin/home.jsf for general users it is /General/home.jsf because login form is shared between different type of users. Where do i specify all these things?

Secondly, i want to have a remember me checkbox at the end of login form. How do i do this? By default, it is submitted to j_security_check servlet and i have no control over its execution. Please help. This doesn't seem so hard but looks like i am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. This is for any newbie who drop on this thread in future. Ok, the solution that i found after much thinking is that i make one folder and one jsp page say flag.jsp. Next, I give access to it to all the roles.

Now, you might be wondering what good would that do?:) Well, just follow it and you might be done. :p

Next in your welcome-file in web.xml mention the url of this file. Thus, when application starts it will go to this url and container will find that i am unauthenticated thus redirect me to login page. That's it. Now, the final part is you can write simple scriplets in our shared roles jsp file and redirect to home based on role. 
Eg. if httpservletrequest#isUserInRole("Admin") then redirect to "/admin/home.jsf" and so on.

Well, this is not so efficient but important thing is that it works! :). This idea accidently bumped to me today. I guess, now i can rest and use container managed security easily. Waiting for your comments.